# getLayer() What Is This Output?

Tags: magento-1.9, module

When I do `$this->getLayer()` in a block template, I get a lot of output but I don't understand it.

I'm trying to make my own module for displaying products based on certain queries and want to understand this `getLayer()` reference.

The code where I saw `getLayer()` was:

```
 protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
             $category2B = $this->getNameInLayout
                //$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId()); //important
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                    $this->addModelTags($category);
                }
            }
            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

I pretty much understand everything here except the layer. Is this referring to a model? Please help me understand exactly what this code is doing.

Whoops, turns out `getLayer` was defined later in the PHP file, but I still don't understand its function...

```
 public function getLayer()
    {
        $layer = Mage::registry('current_layer');
        if ($layer) {
            return $layer;
        }
        return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return the object stored in the Magento registry at key `current_layer`. The registry basically allows objects to access global variables. This value is saved into the registry in a few places, most-notably: \Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Layer::_construct

```
/**
 * Internal constructor
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    Mage::register('current_layer', $this->getLayer(), true);
}
```

Which calls

```
/**
 * Get layer object
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer
 */
public function getLayer()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/layer');
}
```

So, this is a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756753/magento-getsingleton-vs-getmodel-issue) object of Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer, or, if you're using **Enterprise**, `Enterprise_Search_Model_Search_Layer`.

This object is concerned with managing the **layered (faceted) navigation** in Magento. This is the left-side navigation which shows attributes and their values to filter the results by.